# Postgresql - How to select results depending on results of another query

Tags: sql

I'm working on a server where people can easily add, remove friends, and ask for their current ips if they are logged in.

I structured my database to have a first table containing users name, another one containing addresses + a fk on those users and finally another one called 'friends' that contains user -> friend.

For Example :

A, B, C are users, A is friended with C and the other way, B is friended with C but C is not friended with B.

```
Friend table

user friend
 A      C
 C      A
 B      C
```

B wants friends ips. How to i write an sql query that would be able to check if C is also friended with B ?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. `select count(*) from friend where user='c' and friend='b'`?

Comment: Do you need to select friend's ip or to check if C is also friend of B given that B is friend of C?

Comment: I need the list of ips of friends of B. All friends need to have friended B back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you have to check is your friends mututal or not. It could be performed with [left outer join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-join.html)

```
select
    t1.*,
    case when t2.user is not null then 1 else 0 end is_mutual
from test as t1
    left outer join test as t2 on t2.user = t1.friend and t2.friend = t1.user
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b9b3b/3)